# ActionBarSherlock with menu bg color

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock

I want to set up  bg color of my menu on where exit and about, to white , I am working with ActionBarSherlock style and trying to get very simple way.
my style looks like that:

```
<style name="CustomTheme"  parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
</style>
```

what element do I need to add for doing it?

thanks !

Comment: To set abs colors did you try to use actionbarsherlockthemegenerator ? http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100